# Import Error: The Python Imaging Library (PIL) is required to load data from jpeg files

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fetch data from the [LFW dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/labeled_faces.html) using scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_people    
faces = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=60)
```

When doing so I get an *Import Error* message:

> The Python Imaging Library (PIL) is required to load data from jpeg files

The error message indicates that I need to have [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) installed. So I've installed `pillow` from my Jupyter notebook as follows:

```
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} pillow
```

Now I'm able to do `import PIL` but I still get the same error message when trying to fetch data from the LFW dataset.

I'm using Python 3.6. This is the complete trace:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
    143         try:
--> 144             from scipy.misc import imread
    145         except ImportError:

ImportError: cannot import name 'imread'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py in <module>()
     18 try:
---> 19     from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
     20 except ImportError:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     57     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 58     from . import _imaging as core
     59     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
    145         except ImportError:
--> 146             from scipy.misc.pilutil import imread
    147         from scipy.misc import imresize

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py in <module>()
     20 except ImportError:
---> 21     import Image
     22     import ImageFilter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-236-6d1c601c92a3> in <module>()
----> 1 faces = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=60)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in fetch_lfw_people(data_home, funneled, resize, min_faces_per_person, color, slice_, download_if_missing)
    333     faces, target, target_names = load_func(
    334         data_folder_path, resize=resize,
--> 335         min_faces_per_person=min_faces_per_person, color=color, slice_=slice_)
    336 
    337     # pack the results as a Bunch instance

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    560 
    561     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 562         return self._cached_call(args, kwargs)[0]
    563 
    564     def __reduce__(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in _cached_call(self, args, kwargs)
    508                           'directory %s'
    509                         % (name, argument_hash, output_dir))
--> 510             out, metadata = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
    511             if self.mmap_mode is not None:
    512                 # Memmap the output at the first call to be consistent with

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    742         if self._verbose > 0:
    743             print(format_call(self.func, args, kwargs))
--> 744         output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    745         self._persist_output(output, output_dir)
    746         duration = time.time() - start_time

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in _fetch_lfw_people(data_folder_path, slice_, color, resize, min_faces_per_person)
    234     target = np.searchsorted(target_names, person_names)
    235 
--> 236     faces = _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
    237 
    238     # shuffle the faces with a deterministic RNG scheme to avoid having

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\lfw.py in _load_imgs(file_paths, slice_, color, resize)
    147         from scipy.misc import imresize
    148     except ImportError:
--> 149         raise ImportError("The Python Imaging Library (PIL)"
    150                           " is required to load data from jpeg files")
    151 

ImportError: The Python Imaging Library (PIL) is required to load data from jpeg files
```

Why am I getting this import error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below line into your code

```
from PIL import Image
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra details:
Scikit-learn uses `pillow` for loading images.

As per sklearn code in datasets/base.py, `pillow` will be imported upon request:

```
# import PIL only when needed
from ..externals._pilutil import imread
```

...which fails if the library is not installed. To install it via e.g. conda, execute the following command:

```
> conda install --yes --prefix {<environment_path_obtained_from_runnig_sys.prefix>} pillow
```

After you restart your kernel/refresh your IDE to include the new installation(s), there is no need to import the library or any of its components UNLESS you want to process images apart from what sklearn is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Restarting the kernel didn't work, but restarting Jupyter Lab did. I'm not sure why that would happen.